# How to get an efficient and correct drop system by chance

Tags: java, bukkit

I want to get the most efficient and correct drop system in Minecraft according to the odds set by me.

I actually created it like this:

```
double randomChance = getRandom(0, 100);
for(DropObject dropObject : getDropByCategoryAndSource(category, source)) {
    if(randomChance <= dropObject.getChance()) {
        //give item etc.
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that not all items actually drop, only a few. How can I make this a more efficient system to make it work better?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a [Pseudo Random Distribution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161430/calculating-the-constant-c-in-dota-2-pseudo-random-distribution)?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking or what you mean by "efficient". If it's entirely random there's no way to guarantee all items will be dropped--it's random. If you're trying to determine drop *order* then you'd need to run it until everything is dropped, or you'd need to weight/adjust drop chances. Or you can just order by drop chance and always drop the most-likely-to-drop item and move down the list. Or... etc. Without knowing what the actual goal is it's difficult to be specific.

Comment: @DaveNewton The point is, this is the way I usually drop one item, and the rest is completely wrong. I made a test on 10,000 blocks and 3/4 of the items that came out are the same material, and there are others that have a higher percentage and do not fall out.

Comment: Then you'll need to debug--there's little here we can use to assist.

Answer (score 1):

One issue that I see is that since you are generating one number from 0 to 100 and then comparing that against the list. So if you get number 37 from the random method, it means all items with chance equal or higher than 37% will be dropped, which I believe is not the desired behavior.

I don't know the size of that list but maybe you could generate a new random number inside the list loop.